# Detecting last item with display flex

Tags: javascript

Following having applied display flex/ display none with javascript, I want a function that detects the last item that contains display flex, in my example that would be the letter B.

Example code:

```js
const containerDiv = document.querySelector('.container');
const listArray = Array.from(containerDiv.children);

listArray.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.innerHTML === "A" || item.innerHTML === "B"){
      item.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use inline css you can use `class` and `querySelectorAll` for catch last item with `.flex` class

```js
const containerDiv = document.querySelector('.container');
const listArray = Array.from(containerDiv.children);

listArray.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.innerHTML === "A" || item.innerHTML === "B"){
      item.classList.add("flex");
  } else {
     item.classList.add("none");
  }
});
const divFlex = [...containerDiv.querySelectorAll('div.flex')];
console.log(divFlex[divFlex.length - 1])
```

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```